# window.prompt stop working when adding function

Tags: javascript, prompt

```
var user = window.prompt("Welcome to the Vacation Planner. Please enter yourname");
document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML += ", " + user;
var enterDays = document.getElementById("enterDays");
/*
function.calculateDays(){
    var dayMessage = document.getElementById("dayMessage");
    if(enterDays <4){
        dayMessage.innerHTML = "Short trips are always worth it!";
        }
    else if(enterDays<7){
        dayMessage.innerHTML = "Cool, you'll be there for a week"
        }
    else{
        dayMessage.innerHTML = "You'll have plenty of time to relax and have fun!"
        }
}*/
enterDays.onclick = calculateDays;
```

When I enter this code, the window.prompt work correctly. But when I uncomment the function.calculateDays, the window.prompt stop working. Can anybody explain why is it happening and how to solve it?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: That's because `function.calculateDays` is a syntax error. It's `function calculateDays`

Comment: What is the point of vote to close this as a Server Fault question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function.calculateDays` is not valid syntax and will throw a syntax error that will prevent future code from calling, to fix it replace it with `function calculateDays`.